# Wine (and Proton) does not recognize my sim pedals despite Linux doing so

Tags: linux, wine, udev

After testing my Thrustmaster T-LCM positively on jstest-gtk (calibration and mapping working fine), I've followed [this](https://selfmadepenguin.wordpress.com/2024/02/14/how-i-solved-my-gamecontroller-problems/) guide with env variables, but "Wine control" still doesn't recognize them.

[This](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Proton/issues/5126) problem could be related.

I created a udev rule to make the /dev/js1 accessible to users, but I know no command to confirm it (beside, it should be a pointless move since jstest already does take control of them without sudo).
Obviously, this impacts the whole gaming experience since no version of Proton works with them.